# Conditional statements using vue.js with html element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

Im new to vue.js, and Im trying to do a simple `if` with a date field within my ASP.NET MVC project. 
I've seen examples on vue tutorials where the condition is done in the js file, but Im not convinced that this would help me.
I currently have a date field in my ViewModel that has two drop downs. This is for an application form that asks a person how long have they lived at their address. They can select up to 11 months and 6+ years. I have a button that allows them to add another address. When you click this button, the viewModel for the date fields are repeated so they can add another one (stored in a `List`).
 However I want to wrap this around a condition that says only if the date entered is less than 6 years then the button would appear. Like I said, at the min it is there always.

my code for the address and its button is:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide all your addresses in the last 6 years</legend>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PreviousAddresses)
</fieldset>

    <button class="button">Add another previous address</button>
```

What im trying to do is something like `v-if="PreviousAddress < 6"` but I dont think thats right. Can someone help with the syntax?

EDIT: The validation works on the back end. Just need the client side to work with it:

```
 [Minimum(72, ErrorMessage = "Please enter 6 years address history")]
    public int TotalAddressHistoryInMonths
    {
        get
        {
            int totalMonths = CurrentAddress?.Duration?.TotalPeriodInMonths ?? 0;

            if (PreviousAddresses != null)
            {
                foreach (ResidencyInputViewModel residency in PreviousAddresses)
                {
                    totalMonths += residency?.Duration?.TotalPeriodInMonths ?? 0;
                }
            }

            return totalMonths;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have appears to be correct, but can you post the rest of your code. Seeing the data object should help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant more of the vue.js code. From everything you've shown, a v-if statement seems correct. Why don;t you think it is?

Comment: Well PreviousAddress is a List of PreviousAddresses. Meaning when they add an address duration, and click to add another, this is all stored in the List.
I thought about doing something like @{ int TimeAtAddress = PreviousAddresses.Count() },  and do an if TimeAtAddress < 6 around the button, however that will only count the number of addresses within the list, not the duration itself. Which is why I thought vue would help. I just dont know how to use that code behind property within the front

Comment: What if you had a second array of the PreviousAddress durations. Then you could do a v-if based off of the max in that array. Or change the current list to an object with keys of address and duration.